# Firefox 7.0.1 - Mac OS X 10.6.8 - Graphic Issue

Tags: firefox, graphics, macos

I tested this page: http://kulturzentrum-hof.at/index.php?id=9 on several Apple computers (iMac 24", iMac 21,5", MacPro // OSX 10.6.8 and 10.7.1) with Firefox 7.0.1 and I only get on the MacPro (2x 2.66 Ghz Dual-Core) this problem (since 2 or 3 weeks):

When I load the page it looks like this (normally there must be also black-menu-buttons): 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gb5p.jpg

When I take the mouse-pointer and go over the "white"-area the menu-buttons appear, but as red-buttons - and the buttons should be only red by mouseover:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1qxu.jpg

When I start resizing the browser window it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR20N.jpg

or like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HipDn.png

The page shows normally on PC (every browser) and on Mac OSx (Safari/Opera/Chrome) and on some OSx with Firefox.

What is the problem?
Is it a firefox bug?
How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm on a MacBookPro OSX v10.6.8  2x 2.4Ghz Dual core & Firefox 7.0.1. The page looks as it should, and resizes well.

Comment: Firefox 8 is out. You may want to try it if you think it's  a Firefox bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing hardware acceleration in firefox. If that fixes the issue, then report the bug describing the hardware and OS version so that mozilla can track this problem down.

If not, it may be a css rendering bug, do you see it in other websites. If not, it may be a rare combination of css properties triggering a rendering bug in Firefox. Try removing css properties and find which combination couses it. Then you can report the bug with the details.

I don't see the problem on Mac OS X Lion with Firefox 8.0, may be they've solved this bug already.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about the issue,like the graphics card on your machine. I have seen a render issue which is seen only on few graphics cards.

Check this out.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=692759#c92